# OTF Coordinate Transformation on QgsMapCanvas

Tags: coordinate-system, c++, qt, qgsmapcanvas

I want to be able to reproject the current layer's CRS onto the map canvas' CRS. I am using the C++ library with Qt.
I have enable the OTF CRS transformation by calling

```
setCrsTransformEnabled(true);
```

I then set the Map Canvas's CRS using

```
mapCanvas->setDestinationCrs(selector->getSelectedCRS());
```

where selector lets you select the target CRS and mapCanvas is an instance of QgsMapCanvas.
However, once this is called, the current layer disappears. I have tried to reset the extents using setExtent() and refresh().

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent many hours solving the same problem! It happend on QGIS 2.18.20.
After downgrade to 2.14.10 everything`s ok! OTF working fine))